# Matching with partially-observed covariates?

Tags: experiment-design, inference, causality, matching

**Context**

I have a randomized controlled trial where units $i \in N$ have one of two possible values (A or B) on variable x such that $x_i \in \{A,B\}$. Assume equal numbers of observations for all values of x: $n_A = n_B = N / 2$.

Units are assigned at random to one of two "informational" conditions:

- Control: no information to $i$
- Treatment: notification to $i$ of the value of $x_i$.

Notice that the actual content of the treatment can vary by unit but the content itself is not randomized: rather it is only the notification that is randomized. For example, if $x_i = A$, then the treatment would be notification of $A$. $x_i$ is observed $\forall i \in N$.

I can estimate the Average Treatment Effect (ATE) of the treatment via the OLS equation $y_i = a + \beta*t_i + e_i$ where $y_i$ is the outcome of $i$, $t_i$ is 1 if the unit received a notification, $\beta$ is the ATE, and $e_i$ is an error term meeting the usual assumptions.

**Goal**

I am interested in estimating the effect of receiving a notification of $B$ on $y_i$. The problem here is that although **notification about $x_i$** is randomized, **$x_i$ itself** is not randomized and consequently **notification of $x_i = B$ is not randomized**.

### Questions

Matching?

Can I obtain valid causal inferences of the effect of notification of $x_i = B$ solely by conditioning on $x_i$ and dropping all units where $x_i = A$ from my sample? I find this confusing because although I do know the experimental assignment mechanism with certainty, I never see the outcome of receiving notification of $x_i = B$ for those where $x_i = A$. Is this simply a matching estimator where I match on $x_i = B$?

#### $x_i$ only partially observed

Now assume $x_i$ is only observed for units in the treatment condition. In this case, it is not possible to match observations on $x_i$ between the treatment and control. In the absence of a perfect model of $x_i$ based on observables is identification impossible?

Comment: We need more context, do you think $x$ itself affects $y$ or is it only *knowing* or being informed  about $x$ that affects $y$?

Comment: That is a really helpful question! How do you think it affects the results? Consider the case where x has a direct effect and an indirect effect through knowledge of x. In this case, I am guessing this is problematic. If x only operates through information about x, I'd guess this isn't?